# Adding upper level gradle file to an android studio project

Tags: android, gradle

I am attemtping to import an android studio project, however the project seems to be missing an upper-level gradle file.

The imported project has a structure as shown below:
[image]

Any time i attempt to create the top level gradle file I'm unable to, and am given a message saying a file called build.gradle already exists.

How can i add a top level gradle file into this project?

Comment: If you are talking about Project level gradle its Right There .. Under Gradle Script . Change File tree appearance to Android .

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. I need an upper level gradle script that usually looks like this: `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
     }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`